# Call Javascript Function On Form Submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms, event-tracking

I have an email signup form that I need to call a javascript function to track conversions back to google AdWords. I'm having trouble adding the call into the form without breaking it.

Here is the javascript function that needs to be called:

```js
<script>
function gtag_report_conversion(url) {
  var callback = function () {
    if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
      window.location = url;
    }
  };
  gtag('event', 'conversion', {
      'send_to': 'AW-XXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX_XXXID',
      'event_callback': callback
  });
  return false;
}
</script>
```

Here is the form, I can't figure out where to put the call in a way that won't break the form or interfere with any data that needs to be transferred.

```html
<form method="post" class="af-form-wrapper" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="https://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl" >
<div style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" name="meta_web_form_id" value="YYYYYYY" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_split_id" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="listname" value="awlistXXXXX" />
<input id="redirect_XXXXXXXXX" type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://go.pinn.pub/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX?campaignid={campaignid}&adgroupid={adgroupid}&creative={creative}&placement={placement}&target={target}&adposition={adposition}&keyword={keyword}&targetid={targetid}&feeditemid={feeditemid}&gclid={gclid}" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_adtracking" value="Auto_Insurance_Form" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_message" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_required" value="email" />

<input type="hidden" name="meta_tooltip" value="" />
</div>
<div id="af-form-YYYYYYY" class="af-form"><div id="af-header-YYYYYYY" class="af-header"><div class="bodyText"><p>&nbsp;</p></div></div>
<div id="af-body-YYYYYYY" class="af-body af-standards">
<div class="af-element">
<label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-ZZZZZZZZZ"><h3 style="color: white">Are you ready for great rates?</h3></label>
<div class="af-textWrap"><input class="text" id="awf_field-ZZZZZZZZZ" type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder=" Email" tabindex="500" onfocus=" if (this.value == '') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='';} " />
</div><div class="af-clear"></div>
</div><br>
<div class="af-element buttonContainer">
<button name="submit" id="af-submit-image-YYYYYYY" value="Get Started" class="btn btn-orange" alt="Submit Form" tabindex="501" type="submit">Get Started</button><div class="af-clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="af-element privacyPolicy" style="text-align: center"><p style="color: white">We respect your <a title="Privacy Policy" href="https://www.XXXXXXX.com/privacy-policy.html" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">email privacy</a></p>
<div class="af-clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="af-footer-YYYYYYY" class="af-footer"><div class="bodyText"></div></div>
</div>
<div style="display: none;"><img src="https://forms.aweber.com/form/displays.htm" alt="" /></div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    (function() {
        var IE = /*@cc_on!@*/false;
        if (!IE) { return; }
        if (document.compatMode && document.compatMode == 'BackCompat') {
            if (document.getElementById("af-form-YYYYYYY")) {
                document.getElementById("af-form-YYYYYYY").className = 'af-form af-quirksMode';
            }
            if (document.getElementById("af-body-YYYYYYY")) {
                document.getElementById("af-body-YYYYYYY").className = "af-body inline af-quirksMode";
            }
            if (document.getElementById("af-header-YYYYYYY")) {
                document.getElementById("af-header-YYYYYYY").className = "af-header af-quirksMode";
            }
            if (document.getElementById("af-footer-YYYYYYY")) {
                document.getElementById("af-footer-YYYYYYY").className = "af-footer af-quirksMode";
            }
        }
    })();
    -->
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The best and easiest way is  `$("form").submit(function(){})`. This will work with `<input type"submit" />` and `<button type="submit" />`. The `<button type="button" />` will not call `$("form").submit(function(){})`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(){
        alert("Submitted");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="">
  First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" value="Mouse"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(){
        alert("Submitted");
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<form action="">
  First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" value="Mouse"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

```html
$("form").submit(function(){})
```

Comment: @Ryan Thames Try this answer. I hope this will work for you

Answer (score 1):

You can add the [`onsubmit`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp) attribute to the form tag.

---

If you also require to do something before the the form is submitted you can use the jQuery [`.submit`](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) method to do so:

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {
    // DO STUFF...
    return true; // return false to cancel form action
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in **html** like :

```
<element onsubmit="myScript">
```

And in **javascript** you have **2 way** :

```
object.onsubmit = function(){myScript};
```

Or :

```
object.addEventListener("submit", myScript);
```